# Creating an Infinite Scroll with an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, load, infinite

```
$(function() {
   var startY = $('.borderwrap .post:last-child').position().top + $('.borderwrap .post:last-child').outerHeight();
     $(window).scroll(function(){
   checkY();
});
function checkY(){
   if( $(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
       var loadFrom = $('.pagination a').href;
     $('.borderwrap .extended').load(loadFrom  .borderwrap .post, function(response, status, xhr) {
 if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
      $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      }
    });
   }
  }
   window.onLoad = checkY();
});
```

The code above I am trying to load content in an infinite scroll. This is the script I've come up with so far, only issue is the array on `loadFrom'
The html for this looks like this

```
<div class="pagination">
  <a href="">1</a>
  <a href="/post3ksd99999">2</a>
  <a href="/post3ksd8888">3</a>
  <a href="/post3ksd98669">4</a>
</div>
```

So I am having a hard time getting the array to work in the .load() function, and not load multiple pages... I've tried this-

```
for(i in loadFrom){
  $('.borderwrap .extended').load(loadFrom[i]  .borderwrap .post, function(response, status, xhr) {
if (status == "error") {
   var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
   }
 });
}
```

Though this does not work either. any suggestions?

Comment: var loadFrom = $('.pagination a').href; will be undefined . it should be as var loadFrom = $('.pagination a').attr('href'); and please specify which anchor tag you are taking otherwise it will consider the first anchor tag always.

Comment: I want to loop through each one. So that after the first is done and you scroll down it will load second, then scroll down and it will load third..